# Is there any workaround to perform file signing without admin user privilege?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

It works well if PowerShell open as administrator and command ran onto it to sign file.

Tried several approach to signed file with non-admin but unfortunately not success. It returned as 'file not signed exception' everytime.

Is there any workaround to perform file signing without admin user privilege. Is it must to have admin permission in order to perform same activity?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this will work for your scenario but I found this a while ago which will check is PS is running as an Administrator. If it is not, it will restart as an Administrator at which point this would be skipped over.

I wish I could explain how it works. I have never dug into how or why it works.

```
If (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {
    $Arguments = "& '" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "'"
    Start-Process Powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $Arguments
    Break
}
```

Comment: Thank You for swift response, I will make changes in code as per above statements and will check the result.

Comment: Thought I would follow up. I am curious if this was able to solve your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for response but issue was in IIS user account. It  did not appropriate permission to execute powershell. As we have set it to local system it start working.